# Return Default Value When Empty String

Tags: python, django

In Django, I am pulling values from the request object, and want to set a default if it's empty.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
request.POST.get('extended_address', 'this is a default value')
```

But, it's returning an empty string which makes me believe that this only works for None return type.

Is there a way to set a default value for a empty string?

Comment: Use forms, it's what they're for.

Comment: Sorry, not a helpful comment. I am using forms but asking the proper way to utilize.

Comment: Well you could always write something like `request.POST.get('extended_address') or 'this is a default value'`, but that'd be the wrong way to do it in Django.

Comment: I guess that's what I'm asking really. What is the "proper" way to do it in Django? I don't even really know what to search as I'm new to Django and still learning so any advice on what to read about is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forms. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/

Answer (score 2):

`request.POST` returns a QueryDict, which is a subclass of dict. Like any dictionary, `.get()` returns the value for the key if it is present in the dict, and only returns the default if the key is completely absent. If the POST data did include the key, that will be present in the dict as an empty value.

Note that Django has a perfectly good way of pre-processing posted data, and that is through the use of the forms framework.

Comment: Thank you! Would rather use the proper Django method. What would you recommend I look at for the forms framework logic?